# Strange error in a PyCOMPSs application: Script without last "y" not found

Tags: python, distributed-computing, hpc, compss, pycompss

I am trying to run one of the example pyCOMPSs application with version 1.4 and I am getting the following error, which says that the python script without the final "y" can not be found. Do you have any idea what could be the error?

```
xxx:~/xxx_xx/python/increment> runcompss --lang=python increment.py 3 1 2 3 
Using default location for project file:

 /opt/COMPSs/Runtime/scripts/user/../../configuration/xml/projects/project.xml
Using default location for resources file: /opt/COMPSs/Runtime/scripts/user/../../configuration/xml/resources/resources.xml

----------------- Executing increment.py --------------------------

WARNING: IT Properties file is null. Setting default values
[(0)    API]  -  Deploying COMPSs Runtime v1.4 (build 20160725-0937.r2315)
[(2)    API]  -  Starting COMPSs Runtime v1.4 (build 20160725-0937.r2315)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/COMPSs/Runtime/scripts/user/../../../Bindings/python/pycompss/runtime/launch.py", line 85, in <module>
    execfile(app_path)    # MAIN EXECUTION
  File "increment.py", line 92, in <module>
    @task(filePath = FILE_INOUT)
  File "/opt/COMPSs/Bindings/python/pycompss/api/task.py", line 117, in __call__
    if "__init__.py" in os.listdir(path):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'increment.p'

Error running application
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have miss the ./ or the absolute pathe before the python script

```
runcompss --lang=python ./increment.py 3 1 2 3
```

or

```
runcompss --lang=python /path/to/script/increment.py 3 1 2 3
```